# React Webpack Utils Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-start

When running `npm start` I get this error

> Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils'

I even tried deleting and reinstalling. Any help? Here's package.json

```
{
  "name": "tic-tac-toe-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "webpack": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "webpack": "^1.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-command": "^0.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Run npm i, and make sure its in your package, and included.

Comment: @TGarrett it didn’t work :(

Comment: please post your package.json, specifically the "start" line

Comment: I rewrote the question

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "node_modules' folder within the project

Then run `npm install` again

Comment: Now I get “Cannot read property ‘thisCompilation’ of undefined” error